# MS Access Totals Query Sum Field Incorrect Result

Tags: ms-access, sum, distinct

I've built what I believe to be a simple query in MS Access.

Two Tables are involved:

- Properties
- History

The History table includes multiple rows of data for each property, and for various dates.
I'm trying to show the sum of `net_value` for a specific date for properties that share a common area in the property table.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT      Properties.Area
            , History.HIST_DATE
            , History.ID
            , Sum(History.NET_VALUE) AS SumOfNET_VALUE
FROM        Properties INNER JOIN History ON Properties.ID = History.ID
WHERE       (((History.Account_ID)=45))
GROUP BY    Properties.Area, History.HIST_DATE, History.ID
HAVING      (((Properties.Area)="MY AREA") AND 
             ((History.HIST_DATE)=#2/1/2017#));
```

The problem is, the sum field is wildly incorrect.

**Debugging**

The root cause of the issue is that there are multiple entries of `Properties.ID`. 
So I suppose the select is not distinct?  Is there a way around this?
The `Properties.ID` is effectively an account identifier and multiple properties can be associated with it; so I can't really limit `Properties.ID` to one record per ID... thoughts?

Comment: Correct. If you join the table with multiple rows per key field, Sum will multiply. Solution - to join a subquery instead of Properties table. This subquery should return one row per ID

Comment: Could we see an example of the data in the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `History.ID` is a unique field, or at least unique to each property.
By including it in your query the sum will group on that ID as well as the area, so you'll end up with a total per property per area.

No idea where `Account_ID` comes into it, but have included it in the `WHERE` clause anyway.

```
SELECT        Properties.Area
            , History.Hist_Date
            , SUM(History.Net_Value) AS Total_Net_Value
FROM        Properties LEFT JOIN History ON Properties.ID = History.ID
WHERE       History.Account_ID = 45 AND 
            Properties.Area = "My Area"
            History.Hist_Date=#04/27/2018#
GROUP BY      Properties.Area 
            , History.Hist_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT      Properties.Area
            , History.HIST_DATE
            , History.ID
            , Sum(History.NET_VALUE) AS SumOfNET_VALUE
FROM        Properties INNER JOIN History ON Properties.ID = History.ID
WHERE       ((History.Account_ID)=45) 
              AND (Properties.Area)="MY AREA" 
              AND (History.HIST_DATE)=#2/1/2017#))
GROUP BY    Properties.Area, History.HIST_DATE, History.ID;
```

Do not use HAVING clause as Filter except for aggregate function, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp). Use WHERE Part instead.

HAVING would be reasonable for `...HAVING SumOfNET_VALUE > 200`, for example.